# How do I use implicit FTP over TLS

Tags: ftp, ssl, ftps

Using any FTP client (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and tried using `lftp`), I want to be able to make an implicit TLS connection to a FTP server, but I can't quite manage to successfully connect. All I am getting is: `'ls' at 0 [Delaying before reconnect 29]`

Answer (score 44):

Give this a try:

```
$ lftp
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-force true
lftp :~> connect ftp.domain.tld
lftp ftp.domain.tld:~> login <username>
```

**NOTE:** If the server is making use of self signed certificates you may need to add this `set` as well:

```
lftp :~> set ssl:verify-certificate no
```

Comment: and for explicit? can't find how to choose this with lftp

Comment: @tictacbum Does [this other discussion thread](http://lftp.uniyar.ac.narkive.com/Orp3BESx/having-problems-with-explicit-ssl-ftps#post6) help?

Comment: Sorry, but with quite recent `lftp` 4.8.1 it doesn't work: ```gdubicki@mac ~ $ lftp -d
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-force true
lftp :~> connect ftp.myserver.com
---- Resolving host address...
---- 1 address found: 111.222.111.222
lftp ftp.myserver.com:~> login someuser
Password:
lftp someuser@ftp.myserver.com:~> ls
---- Connecting to ftp.myserver.com (111.222.111.222) port 21
<--- 220 Service ready for new user.
---> FEAT
<--- 530 Access denied.
---> AUTH TLS
<--- 234 Command AUTH okay; starting TLS connection.``` - you can see that this is explicit SSL because of `AUTH` command is used.

Comment: @Lluís : see my answer for both implicit and explicit.

Answer (score 8):

For **implicit** TLS / SSL using `lftp` please do these commands:

```
connect ftps://ftp.domain.tld
```

Note that this will connect you to port 990 directly using TLS.

For **explicit** TLS / SSL:

```
set ftp:ssl-force true
connect ftp://ftp.domain.tld
```

...which will connect you to port 21 with plain-text initially but then will explicitly switch you to TLS using FTP protocol `AUTH` command.

You can add `-d` parameter to `connect` (like `connect -d ftp://ftp.domain.tld`) to enable debug output to ensure that you are connecting using the method you want.

Tested on `lftp` v. 4.8.4.

Answer (score 2):

In case the link that @summea refers to above disappears, the pertinent info that solved this issue for me was this option:

```
set ftp:ssl-auth TLS
```

Comment: This option alone does nothing as it's the default auth method (inless call to FEAT responds with SSL, but it's deprecated nowadays).